# ¿Qué tipo de oración es "De modo que el asedio hubiera terminado aquel día"?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Qué tipo de oración es la oración en negrita?

> **De modo que el asedio hubiera terminado aquel día**, de no haber sido
>   porque H. S. vino a pasar la Navidad con su prima, y la vida cambió
>   para ambas.

Una vez he leído que "de modo que" puede tener valor de finalidad y puede ser sustituida por "para que".

No estoy totalmente segura pero no me parece correcta la versión de la frase mencionada con "para que".

Mi otra opción sería sustituir "de modo que" por "así que" (pero tampoco estoy segura si sería correcto interpretarlo así). Entonces ¿tenemos una oración consecutiva?

Por otro lado, estoy tratando de identificar la oración principal. ¿Puede ser que esta misma frase "De modo que el asedio hubiera terminado aquel día" sea la oración principal y "de no haber sido porque H. S. vino a pasar la Navidad con su prima" la oración condicional?

Comment: Tu idea de "así que" me parece bien.

Answer (score 4):

Antes que nada, convengamos que "de modo que el asedio hubiera terminado aquel día" no es una oración completa, sino que forma parte de la oración que finaliza con "... y la vida cambió para ambas".

En realidad, "de modo que", que en otras oraciones introduce proposiciones adverbiales de finalidad ("Le di un pañuelo **de modo que** (= para que) pudiera secarse las lágrimas") o de consecuencia ("Le di un pañuelo **de modo que** (= así que) pudo secarse las lágrimas"), en este caso introduce la proposición principal. En efecto, "de modo que" funciona como un conector con la oración que sigue, cuya proposición principal es "el asedio hubiera (= habría) terminado aquel día".

El texto en cuestión ha sido extraído de "El amor en los tiempos de cólera", de Gabriel García Márquez, y dice:

*El arzobispo no fue. De modo que el asedio hubiera terminado aquel día, de no haber sido porque Hildebranda Sánchez vino a pasar la Navidad con su prima, y la vida cambió para ambas.*

"De modo que" vincula el hecho de que el arzobispo no fue con la posibilidad de que el asedio a Fermina Daza (el personaje que estaba siendo objeto del asedio) hubiera terminado. Por lo general, las locuciones que finalizan con "que" son subordinantes, pero no es el caso aquí, puesto que introduce una nueva oración. En el texto analizado, "De modo que" no es un nexo intra- sino inter-oracional, y su sentido es consecutivo. Prueba de ello es que, aunque menos elegante, podríamos reemplazarlo por "Por lo tanto" o "En tal sentido" o "Por consiguiente".

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el principal problema para entender la frase está en el uso que hace del subjuntivo con valor condicional. En mi opinión, aunque este uso es aceptable en algunos casos, aquí no (supongo que García Márquez está imitando el lenguaje de la zona, como hace otras veces). Si cambias el subjuntivo por el condicional, queda bastante más clara:

> De modo que el asedio **habría** terminado aquel día [...]

Por tanto, tenemos aquí una oración consecutiva que, como bien explica Gustavson en su respuesta, enlaza con la anterior.